Can you help me and my grandmother
My grandmother told me that she owns a bitcoin which she was gifted a long time ago before they were valuable, she doesn't know anything other then the email she used. I have some expertise in tech but am in no way familiar with bitcoin
Could we possibly retrieve said bitcoin by mail?
